# Roda - Assets duplicating every time I save

Tags: roda

I'm building a very simple app in Roda and for some reason every time I save a css or js file it is compiling the assets and creating a duplication in the public assets folder. I have about 20 of the same css and js file but each with a different asset precompile prefix. Here is the code:

```
require 'roda'
require_relative './app'

class App < Roda
  plugin :render
  plugin :assets, css: 'style.scss', js: 'app.js'
  compile_assets

  route do |r|
    r.assets

    r.root do
      view 'app'
    end
  end
end
```

The app server is running with rerun, I don't know if that's relevant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assets plugin relies on SHA digest to name the compiled assets to allow for [subresource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) checks. Every time you make a change in your `app.js` file, the digest will change, so the new file name is generated.

You can disable it by setting `sri` [option](https://roda.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Roda/RodaPlugins/Assets.html#module-Roda::RodaPlugins::Assets-label-Plugin+Options) to `nil` in the plugin method call:

```
class App < Roda
  plugin :assets, css: 'style.scss', js: 'app.js', sri: nil
end
```

In production you probably want to leave SRI on. Especially if you plan on using a CDN.